# C++ bitwise OR operator

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

```
bool OrderUtils::shouldCptyAutoexecute(int Id)
{

bool res = 
    dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).getWhitelabelType() == "ABCD";
if (!res)
    res |= dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).getIsPlc() == 1;

return res;
}
```

The above code checks for 2 Id's and returns true to res if any of the id is present in the database.

Can you suggest a way in which I can compare one more value from the databse table and return true to the value res..Also can you explain what does the second if statement do and the bitwise OR operator?

Comment: If I didn't know better, I would have thought this was Java. You could have simplified this by using a container.. like an associative array.

Comment: @user1931177, you want to compare 3 fields, right?

Comment: Is the third comparison in conjunction with a logical AND operation, as in (A || B) && C, or is it just a third logical OR condition, A || B || C. ? In other words, please specify the logical boolean condition you want your third field established with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sir, just let the short-circuit eval do this for you:

```
return dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).getWhitelabelType() == "ABCD" ||
       dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).getIsPlc() == 1;
```

If the first is true, the second will not fire. Moreover, I assure you a remotely-reasonable optimizing compiler will not re-fire `instance().getVal(id)` if the returned object has not changed between the `getWhitelabelType()` and `getisPlc()` calls. In fact, i would all-but-guarantee it if `getWhiteLabelType()` is `const`. (and it certainly looks like it should be).

Regarding the bit work. The expression was pretty-much whacked. though it will work. Unless I read it wrong (and trust me, the list of people that will tell me I am will let me know quickly) it is performing a boolean eval, promoting the resulting true/false `bool` to an `int`, promoting the current value of `res` from `bool` to `int` (which is zero, so nothing special there), bitwise-OR-ing that with the expression `int`, then demoting the final int back to a bool to store in `res` . I'm surprised this doesn't flag at least a warning on the compiler.

It likely should have been `if (!res) res ||= expr`, and even then, it is pointless, as you can just use short circuit eval as in the top of this answer to cut out the local `res` entirely. Consider if `res` were `false`. Then the equivalent expression would be `res = false || expr`. But thats just `res = expr`. In the `!res` state it executes in, you may as well just use an assignment.

Finally, regarding adding a third field to your eval, it depends entirely on how you want it added. for an additional logical OR it is pretty simple.

For an expression like (A || B || C) you can just

```
return dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).AField() == ATestValue ||
       dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).BField() == BTestValue ||
       dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).CField() == CTestValue;
```

For more complex operations, some judicious use of parenthesis will go a long way. For example, to return `(A || B) && C`:

```
return (dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).AField() == ATestValue ||
        dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).BField() == BTestValue) &&
       dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).CField() == CTestValue;
```

Or perhaps `(A && C) || (B && !C)` (ok this is getting a little overboard...)

```
return (dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).CField() == CTestValue) 
       ? (dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).AField() == ATestValue)
       : (dummyCache::instance().getVal(Id).BField() == BTestValue);
```

Comment: +1, still need to `Can you suggest a way in which I can compare one more value from the databse table and return true to the value res`?